# Covering a compact set with balls whose centers do not belong to other balls.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

Let $K\subset \Bbb R^n$ be a compact set such that each $x\in K$ is associated with a positive number $r_x>0$.

> **Claim**: $K$ can be covered by a family of balls 
>   $$
> \mathcal B = \{ B(x_i,r_i) : i=1,\dots,k\ \},
> $$
>   where $r_i := r_{x_i}$, such that for any distinct $i,j \le k$, we have 
>   $$
> x_i\notin B(x_j,r_j) \quad\text{and}\quad x_j\notin B(x_i,r_i).
> $$

Is the claim true without any additional assumptions on $r_x$'s?

At first I thought of using Zorn's lemma to extract a maximal subfamily of balls from $\mathcal F = \{B(x,r_x/2) : x\in K \}$ such that any pair of balls is disjoint. However, enlarging the radii by a factor of $2$ may not be a cover of $K$ so this approach may not work.

Comment: Sometimes trying to construct a counterexample (and failing, since the statement is true) helps get insight.  For example, let $n = 1, K = [0, 1]$.  Try to construct such a correspondence
$$
x \mapsto r_{x}
$$
that the statement would fail.

Comment: @jgon yeah, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: @GuidoA., I think that even in the more general case, when $r_{x}$ has any positive upper bound, the claim is correct, and the finite covering can be constructed by induction.  Thus, if we have any chance at a counterexample, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there must exist values $r_{x} < \epsilon$.

Comment: @avs I must admit that I still have no idea how it could be done. Do you have a sketch of the proof in mind?

Comment: @avs The case when $r_x$ is unbounded above is easy: just choose $B(x, r_x)$ where $r_x > \operatorname{diam}(K)$ (which is finite, as $K$ is compact).

Comment: When $r_x$ is continuous, there's an inductive proof, where at step $\alpha$ we add the open ball of maximal radius whose center is not in one of our prior open balls (the ball of maximal radius exists by continuity and compactness). I'm not seeing how to justify that this terminates in finitely many steps directly (it's not even clear to me that it should). However, we should get a cover by transfinite induction, and then we can take a finite subcover by compactness.

Comment: There might be another problem with the idea of enlarging the radii by a factor of $2$. Say $p$ and $q$ are distance $1$ apart, and $B_p$, $B_q$ are disjoint balls centered at $p,q$ respectively, of radii $r_p=\frac23$ and $r_q=\frac13$, before the enlargement by a factor of $2$. After enlargement, the point $q$ gets swallowed by the ball around $p$ with radius $\frac43$.

Comment: @jgon It is enough to assume that $r_x$ is upper semicontinuous (achieves its max on every non-empty closed set). You don't need transfinite induction, just do it for natural numbers $n$. It stops at finitely many steps. If not, Case 1 the radii converge down to a positive number $q$, contradiction since the centers are distance $\ge q$ apart, would form an infinite closed-and-discrete set. Case 2, the radii decrease to $0$, pick a subsequence of centers converging to some $x$, then the (or some) ball around $x$ shows we must have failed to pick the largest ball at each step, a contradiction.

Comment: @Mirko Good points. I figured it would have to terminate after finitely many steps, but I couldn't see the proof. That makes sense.

Comment: The mapping $x\mapsto r_x$ is not assumed to have any regularity though, not even measurability.

Comment: @jgon What makes you sure that at step $\alpha$ the open ball of maximal radius whose center is not in one of the prior open balls does not contain the center of one of the prior balls?

Comment: @PaulFrost Because the radius at step $\alpha$ is at most the smallest of the prior radii.

Comment: The positive integers N with $r_n=n$ show that the condition that K is bounded is essential. Assuming that K is bounded,it doesn't seem as easy to show that the condition that K is closed is essential. This problem feels to be more closely related to metric spaces,than to topological spaces. Perhaps add a tag metric-spaces? Could it be that the Claim holds for every abstract bounded metric space? The Claim holds if K is finite, perhaps some kind of a Tukey Lemma argument could solve the general case? If $U_n$ is the union of the balls with radius $>1/n$ and K compact,then some $U_n$ contains K

Comment: @avs Could you prove the claim if you assume that there are positive real $m\le M$ with $0<m\le r_x\le M$ for all $x$? If so, could you do it only assuming that $K$ is a bounded subset of $R^n$ (assuming again that there are $0<m\le M$ with $m\le r_x\le M$ for all $x$)? The latter would answer positively the OP question.

Comment: @Mirko, not without $K$ being closed.  See my community wiki attempt at an answer.

Comment: @avs Apparently you mean you don't have a proof, unless you assume that $K$ is both closed and bounded. But my question should be interpreted as follows. Do you have an example (with a proof) of a bounded but not closed K, and a ball assignment for each point, such that the Claim as in OP fails? What if K is bounded, and $r_x\ge m$ for some $m>0$ and all $x$?  Regarding the community answer you posted, I follow the ideas and I see it works if $r_x$ is upper semicontinuous (which was sketched in the comments, but you provide more details), but I believe the general case seems to remain open.

Comment: @Mirko, you are right on all accounts.

I may be able to generalize the community wiki answer I posted to cover the case when $m$ is not lower semicontinuous, but I am not sure I can get it to cover the case when $K$ is bounded but not necessarily closed.  Our ability to extract a finite subcover for a non-compact $K$ then will have to come from the properties of the cover constructed, not from those of $K$.

Comment: @jgon if you formally proceed by transfinite induction, you realize in the end, after it stops, that your collection is finite. Indeed, the cover you get is minimal: If you remove any ball then we no longer have a cover, since the center of the removed ball is not covered by any of the other balls. A minimal cover of a compact space must be finite. Perhaps the transfinite construction might be relevant in a different context, if we don't insist that $K$ is compact, but only that it is bounded (though then upper semicontinuity need not help,and I do not have any specific way to proceed in mind)

Comment: @Mirko Ah that's also a good way to see it. To be honest, I didn't think too hard about whether we'd end up with a finite collection at the end, since compactness of course allows us to reduce to a finite collection. But yeah minimality of the cover should have made it clear to me that it was finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt (I hope successful) at a positive answer, at least for $n=1$, i.e. when the compact set $K$ is a subset of the real line $\Bbb R^1$. It relies on the linear order of the line, and I do not immediately see how to generalize to $\Bbb R^n$, for $n\ge2$. By the way, the concept discussed in this question resembles the notion of so-called $D$-space in general topology, and in that context the Sorgenfrey line (i.e. the real line with the upper limit topology) is an important example. The class of $D$-spaces was introduced by van Douwen and Pfeffer in 1978:

Some properties of the Sorgenfrey line and related spaces.
Washek F. Pfeffer and Eric K. van Douwen
Pacific J. Math. Volume 81, Number 2 (1979), 371-377.
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102785280

and it remains an open question if every paracompact space is a $D$-space. There are variations of this concept, including strong $D$-space, and these properties are defined using so-called open neighborhood assignments, ONA, for a topological space $X$: For each point $x$, an open neighborhood $U_x$ containing $x$ is assigned. Then one picks a so-called kernel: A subset $D$ of $X$ so that the neighborhoods assigned to points in the kernel cover the space $X$. If one could always pick a kernel that is closed-and-discrete, then $X$ is called a $D$-space. (Here "always" means for every ONA, i.e. every assignment of neighborhoods $U_x$.) If a certain additional condition is satisfied (namely, the kernel $D$ is locally-finite in the topology generated by the ONA), then the space $X$ is called strongly $D$ (and this latter property appears to be fairly restrictive). In the present question, one asks for even more: each point in the kernel is contained in only its own neighborhood, and not in the neighborhoods assigned to other points in the kernel. But, at least, we work in a compact metric space, or even a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$, and to each $x$ we assign an open ball centered at $x$, not an arbitrary neighborhood (the latter option tends to make the problem less tractable). I might have had some advantage, being familiar with some of the results on $D$-spaces (and in particular, about the Sorgenfrey line).

I think I have a yes answer to the OP when $n=1$, i.e. when the compact $K$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^1$. I do not immediately see how to generalize to $\Bbb R^n$ for $n\ge2$ (though, for $D$-spaces, there is a paper by de Caux:
Peter de Caux, Yet another property of the Sorgenfrey plane,
Top. Proc. 6, no 1 (1981) pp. 31-43.   http://www.topo.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v06/tp06105s.pdf
that might have relevant ideas or techniques, that deals with powers $S^n$ of the Sorgenfrey line $S$, showing that each such power is a (hereditarily) $D$-space).

Let $K$ be a compact subset of the real line, and let for each $x\in K$ a positive radius $r_x$ is fixed, so 
each $x$ is covered by the ball $B(x,r_x)$. 
Let $x_0=\min K$ and by transfinite recursion, if 
$1\le\alpha<\omega_1$ and $x_\beta$ are defined for all $\beta<\alpha$, let $U_\alpha=\cup_{\beta<\alpha}B(x_\beta,r_{x_\beta})$ 
and let $Y_\alpha=K\setminus U_\alpha$. 
If $K\not\subseteq U_\alpha$, i.e. if $Y_\alpha\not= 
\emptyset$, then let $x_\alpha=\min Y_\alpha$. (Use that each $Y_\alpha$ is compact and has a smallest element, i.e. $\min$ with respect to the usual order of the reals.) There is a smallest countable ordinal $\gamma\ge1$ such that $Y_\gamma=\emptyset$, i.e. 
$K\subseteq U_\gamma$ but $K\not\subseteq U_\alpha$  if $\alpha<\gamma$ (where $U_0=\emptyset$).

Claim 1. $\gamma$ is a successor ordinal, i.e. $\gamma=\delta+1$ for some $\delta<\omega_1$.

Proof. If $\gamma$ were a limit ordinal, then $K$ would be a strictly increasing union of the open sets 
$U_\alpha$, $\alpha<\gamma$ (more precisely, 
a strictly increasing union of the relatively open sets 
$U_\alpha\cap K$, since 
$x_{\alpha+1}\in U_{\alpha+1}\setminus U_\alpha$ for each $\alpha<\gamma$). 
That is, the cover 
$\{U_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$ of $K$ would have no finite subcover, a contradiction.

Let $X=\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$. By Claim 1, 
$X=\{x_\alpha:\alpha\le\delta\}$. 
Note that Claim 1 and the above construction imply that $\max K\in B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$.

Claim 2. $X$ is well-ordered as a subset of $K$ (or 
equivalently, as a subset of $\Bbb R$).

Proof. It is immediate from the construction that $X$ 
is order-isomorphic to $\gamma$, where as usual 
$\gamma=\{\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}=[0,\gamma)$.

If $X\subseteq B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$ then we 
are done. If not then we continue as follows.

Claim 3. If the set $P=X\setminus B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$ is non-empty, then it has a maximal element.

Proof. Note that $P$ is an initial segment of $X$, 
say $P=\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\mu\}$ for some countable ordinal $\mu\le\delta$. If $P$ did not have a maximal element, then $\mu$ is a limit ordinal. For each $\alpha<\mu$ we have $U_\alpha\subseteq(-\infty,x_\alpha)$. 
Let $q=\sup P = \sup_{\alpha<\mu} x_\alpha$. Then 
$q\in\overline P\subseteq K$ and 
$U_\mu=\cup_{\alpha<\mu}U_\alpha\subseteq(-\infty,q)$. Since
$q=\sup P=\sup U_\mu=\min (K\setminus U_\mu)$, 
we have $q=x_\mu$. 
Note that $x_\alpha<\inf B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$ 
for all $\alpha<\mu$, 
hence $q=x_\mu\le\inf B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$, 
and $x_\mu\not\in B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$, 
implying $x_\mu\in P$, a contradiction, which completes the proof of Claim 3.

Let $z_0=x_\delta$ and $C_0=B(z_0, r_{z_0})$. 
If $X\setminus C_0\not=\emptyset$, then (using Claim 3) let $z_1=\max (X\setminus C_0)$. 
Note that (as is easy to verify) if 
$C_1=C_0\cup B(z_1, r_{z_1})$ then 
$[z_1,\infty)\cap K\subseteq C_1$. 
If $X\not\subseteq C_1$ then let 
$z_2=\max (X\setminus C_1)$ (the proof that $\max$ exists is similar to Claim 3), and let 
$C_2=C_1\cup B(z_2, r_{z_2})$. 
Inductively, $z_{n+1}=\max (X\setminus C_n)$ 
and $C_{n+1}=C_n\cup B(z_{n+1}, r_{z_{n+1}})$, 
with $z_{n+1}<z_n$ and 
$[z_{n+1},\infty)\cap K\subseteq C_{n+1}$.

Since the $z_n$ form a decreasing sequence 
in the well-ordered set $X$, this process 
must terminate in finitely many steps, i.e. 
there is $m\ge0$ such that $X\subseteq C_m$. 
Then also $K\subseteq C_m$, since $C_m$ covers 
everything in $K$ starting at the top $x_\delta$ 
(with $C_0=B(z_0, r_{z_0})=B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})$ covering $\max K$) and going back to the bottom $x_0=\min X =\min K$, without omitting 
any elements of $K$ in between. (Exercise.)

Then the family $\mathcal B = \{ B(z_n,r_{z_n}) : n=0,\dots,m\ \}$ shows that the Claim in OP holds.

This answers the question positively for the case when 
$K$ is a compact subspace of the real line $\Bbb R$.

Edit. At hindsight the proof could be more instructive and unified if one first proves the following Claim 0, which could then be applied in the proofs of both Claim 1 and Claim 3 above.

Claim 0. $X$ is closed (as a subspace of $K$ and of $\Bbb R$).

Proof. It is more or less done in each of the proofs of Claim 1 and Claim 3, but here is 
how it could go. Since $X$ is well-ordered, 
it is enough to show that whenever $X$ contains 
an increasing sequence $a_0 < a_1 < \dots$ 
where $a_n=x_{\beta_n}$ with 
$\beta_n < \beta_{n+1}$ for all natural numbers $n<\omega$, and if we let $a=\sup_n a_n$ 
then  $a\in X$. 
Indeed, $a_n=x_{\beta_n}\in 
U_{\beta_n+1}$ 
and $U_{\beta_n}\subseteq (-\infty,x_{\beta_n})$, 
hence if $\beta=\sup_n \beta_n$ then 
$U_\beta=\cup_{n<\omega}U_{\beta_n}\subseteq 
(-\infty,a)$. Since $K$ is closed and 
$a_n\in X\subseteq K$ we have $a\in K$, and 
$a=\min (K\setminus U_\beta)$, hence 
$a=x_\beta\in X$, showing that $X$ is closed, 
completing the proof of Claim 0. (In particular, $X$ as a subspace of $K$ and of $\Bbb R$ is not only order-isomorphic to $\lambda$ but also 
homeomorphic to it.)

With the aid of Claim 0, here are some more details justifying that the 
family $\mathcal B = \{ B(z_n,r_{z_n}) : n=0,\dots,m\ \}$ is indeed a cover of $K$. 
As above, let $z_0=x_\delta$ and 
$C_0=B(z_0, r_{z_0})$. 
By construction we have that 
$\max K\in B(x_\delta, r_{x_\delta})=C_0$. 
Since $X$ is well-ordered, we could let 
$y_0=\min(X\cap C_0)$. 
If $y_0\not=x_0=\min K$, that is if 
$X\not\subseteq C_0$ or equivalently 
$X\setminus C_0\not=\emptyset$ 
then let 
$z_1=\sup(X\setminus C_0)$. Since (by Claim 0) 
$X$ is closed, we have $z_1\in X$. But $z_1\not\in C_0$ since $C_0$ is open, hence 
$z_1<y_0$, and $y_0$ is the immediate successor 
of $z_1$ in the well-order $X$. It follows 
(by construction of $X$) that 
$y_0=\min (K\cap(z_1,\infty)\setminus 
B(z_1, r_{z_1}))$ so that there are no 
elements of $K$ "between" $B(z_1, r_{z_1})$ 
and $B(z_0, r_{z_0})$ (that is, between 
$z_1$ and $z_0$) that are not covered by 
the set 
$C_1=B(z_1, r_{z_1})\cup B(z_0, r_{z_0})=
B(z_1, r_{z_1})\cup C_0$. 
We can continue: 
Let $y_1=\min(X\cap C_1)$. 
If $y_1\not=x_0$, that is if 
$X\not\subseteq C_1$ or equivalently 
$X\setminus C_1\not=\emptyset$ 
then let 
$z_2=\sup(X\setminus C_1)$. 
Then $z_2\in X$ and $y_1$ is the immediate successor of $z_2$ in $X$, etc.

Comment: Seems pretty complicated for me as I have very little background in axiomatic set theory but thank you for the detailed answer. I will need sometime to make sense of this.

Comment: It is not that much set theory that was used. $\omega_1$ is the set of all countable ordinals (and at the same time it is the first uncountable ordinal), and some authors denote it by $\Omega$ (e.g. including perhaps Munkres and Willard, in general topology texts). And $\omega$ is the first infinite ordinal, same as the set of all finite ordinals, same as the set of all non-negative integers,or the set of all natural numbers including $0$. There is also some transfinite recursion or induction on $\omega_1$ but $\omega_1$ is perhaps the best (basic/ubiquitous) place to illustrate this technique

Comment: What I meant is that I have next to zero knowledge of ordinals arithmetic or transfinite induction. I still haven't got the time to read it so maybe it might not be as difficult as I imagined.

Comment: @BigbearZzz It is not required. Mirko's proof can be recast as follows. Let $K\subset [0,1]$, $0\in K$ and let $z$ be the infimum of $x$ such that $K_x=K\cap [0,x]$ has no good cover by disks centered at $K_x$ (we call such $x$ bad; $0$ is certainly good). Then $z\in K$ (otherwise you can diminish it not changing the intersection). Also $z$ is bad (If $z$ were good, we would also have $x$ good for all $x$ slightly larger than $z$).

Comment: @BigbearZzz Now take $D_z=D(z,r_z)$. If $r_z>z$, $K_z\subset D_z$, i.e., $z$ is good. Otherwise $z'=z-r_z$ is good, so we can cover $K_{z'}$ by disks centered in $K_{z'}$. If that cover covers $z$, $z$ is good. If not, add $D_z$ to it and $z$ is good again. In any case we have a contradiction, so $z$ does not exist, i.e., there are no bad $x$.

Comment: @Mirko It seems like the reason your could only prove it in one dimensional is because it is false in higher dimensions, as demonstrated by fedja in a related post on MO
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331767/a-besicovitch-type-covering-theorem
Thanks a lot for solving the $1$-dimensional case though.

Comment: @fedja thank you for recasting the proof, avoiding transfinite induction. If either version there seem to be two parts of the proof, first go forward (from left endpoint to the right), then (in your proof starting at $z$) go backward to improve on the cover that you got on the first pass. For what it is worth, this could be generalized to any compact LOTS (linear order which is compact in the interval, or order, topology) and a neighborhood assignment of order-convex open sets. But I saw on MO this all related to Besicovitch-type theorems, one likely wouldn't want to stray away from $\Bbb R^n$

Answer (score 1):

I think @Fedja's counterexample on the [MO counterpart](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331767/a-besicovitch-type-covering-theorem) of the question works pretty well. His/her answer is worthy of mentioning here:

> This trivial counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ should have taken me five minutes. Instead, I spent almost two days. The moral is the usual one: after 50 you'd better give up on mathematics.
>
> Let $y,z$ be 2 points at distance $1$ from each other. We shall construct by induction a sequence of points $x_j$ and radii $r_j>\max(d(x_j,y),d(x_j,z))$ such that $x_j\to y$ when $j$ is odd, $x_j\to z$ when $j$ is even, $x_j$ do not lie on the line $yz$, $\max(d(x_j,y),d(x_j,z))<1$, the disk $D(x_j,\max(d(x_j,y),d(x_j,z)))$ contains  $x_1,\dots, x_j$ but $x_{j+1}\notin D(x_j,r_j)$ . If you choose the radius $\rho$ for $y$ and $z$ small enough so that the corresponding disks do not contain $x_1$, you'll get a bad configuration.
>
> Indeed, an attempt to choose $x$ or $y$ as one of the centers results in the exclusion of all the centers $x_j$, after which covering $x_1$ gets impossible.
>
> Out of $x_i$, we can choose only one (if $i<j$, then $x_i\in D(x_j,r_j)$). But then, if we choose $x_i$, the point $x_{i+1}$ is not covered.
>
> Now the sequences. Start with any $x_1$ very close to $y$ and not on the line $yz$ so that $d(x_1,z)<1$. Assume that $x_1,x_2,\dots x_j$ and $r_1,\dots,r_{j-1}$ are already constructed and, say $j$ is odd, so $x_j$ is close to $y$. Then the circles centered at $x_j$ and $x$ containing $z$ cross at an angle, so $D(y,1)\setminus \bar D(x_j,d(x_j,z))$ is an open set containing points arbitrarily close to $z$. Choose $x_{j+1}$ to be any point in that difference that doesn't lie on the line $yz$  and satisfies $d(y,x_{j+1})\ge 1-d(z,x_{j+1})>\max_{i\le j}d(z,x_i)+d(z,x_{j+1})\ge \max_{i\le j}d(x_i,x_{j+1})$ and choose $r_j$ anywhere between $d(x_j,z)$ and $d(x_j,x_{j+1})$.
>
> Clearly, we can keep $x_j$ with odd indices at the distance $<1/3$ to $y$ and converging to $y$  and similarly for even indices and $z$.

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer since I'm afraid it will go unnoticed in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thoroughly checked the following, so it's a community wiki.

Suppose $K$ is compact, and suppose $r_{x}$ is lower semicontinuous, bounded above, and bounded away from zero:
$$
0 < m \leq r_{x} \leq M,
$$
and suppose $M$ is the least upper bound.  Therefore, this bound is attained at some $x_{M} \in K$.  (Note: I do *not* require $r_{x}$ to be continuous.  The attention of the bound follows from other considerations.)

Accordingly, one has $r_{x_{M}} = M$.

Let $x_{0} = x_{M}$ and let
$$
K_{1} = K \setminus B(x_{0}, r_{x_{0}}),
$$
where
$$
B(x_{0}, r_{x_{0}}) = B(x_{M}, M).
$$

The restriction of $r_{x}$ to the compact set $\overline{K_{1}}$ is bounded above, hence attains its least upper bound on some $x_{1} \in \overline{K_{1}}$:
$$
r_{x_{1}} = \sup \; \left\{ r_{x} \; : \; x \in \overline{K_{1}} \right\} \leq r_{x_{0}}.
$$
By construction, $x_{1}$ is not in $B(x_{0}, r_{x_{0}})$, and $x_{0}$ is not in $B(x_{1}, r_{x_{1}})$.

We next put
$$
K_{2} = K_{1} \setminus B(x_{1}, r_{x_{1}})
$$
and pick such an 
$$
x_{2} \in \overline{K_{2}}
$$
and which $r_{x}$ attains its least upper bound on $\overline{K_{2}}$.  Note that $B(x_{2}, r_{x_{2}})$ contains neither of $x_{1}, x_{2}$, and that $x_{2}$ is not in either of $B(x_{0}, r_{x_{0}}), B(x_{1}, r_{x_{1}})$.  So, of the three balls constructed so far, none contains the center of another.

After at most transfinitely many repetitions of this step, we get a (possibly finite) sequence $B(x_{i}, r_{x_{i}})$ of balls where none of the balls contains the center of another.  These balls constitute a cover of $K$.  Extracting, if necessary, a finite subcover, we obtain a collection of balls with the desired property.

Comment: May I ask why must the least upper bound $M$ be attained? The mapping $x\mapsto r_x$ is not assumed to be continuous.

Comment: Sure.  If $M$ is the least upper bound, then $K$ contains a sequence $y_{k}$ with $r_{y_{k}}$ converging to $M$.  Since $K$ is compact, $y_{k}$ has subsequence that converges to some $y \in K$.  What is $r_{y}$?  It can be neither $< M$ nor $> M$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Notice, I am not assuming $r_{x}$ to be continuous.

Comment: @avs: No, it does not make sense: You are implicitly assuming (semi)continuity of $r_x$: The value $r_y$ can easily be $<M$.

Comment: How?  The sequence of the values $r_{y_{k}}$ converges to $M$.

Comment: Why can't $r_y<M$? Your argument seems weird to me.

Comment: We can have $r_{y_{k}} < M$ for the individual values of $k$, but we chose the sequence $y_{k}$ so that $r_{y_{k}}$ converges to $M$.  We were careful to make $M$ the **least** upper bound.

Comment: That's upper semicontinuity you're assuming.

Comment: The counterexample is easy. Take $K=[0,1]$ and $r_x=x$ whenever $0<x<1$ and $r_0=r_1=1/2$. Here $M=1$.

Comment: I see.  In that case, we can pick an arbitrarily small $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ and claim that $K$ has a point $x_{0}$ at which $r_{x_{0}} > M - \epsilon_{0}$.  I'll think about how to revise the proof accordingly, so as to preserve the required condition on the sequence of the balls constructed.